# C program to display a jpeg or bmp or pcx file

Tags: c

What is the code in 'c' to display a picture file like jpeg file or bmp file or pcx file.
For example the picture may be available in desktop and the program during execution must be given the path of the file as input and should display the image.(If it is in command line,it'll be excellent).

Platform:Windows xp

Turbo c compiler(or turboc++)

Comment: You will have more chances for good answers if you add information about the operating system used, considered technologies/frameworks etc.

Comment: Which operating system? Do you realize that "the code" to fully read e.g. a JPEG file might be thousands of lines?

Comment: this is not part of standard C library and therefore it is dependent on your environment, please post more details on your actual requirements and environment

Comment: .PCX?  Srsly?  Is this message being sent through some sort of time warp or alternate reality where people are using Deluxe Paint IX?

Comment: This question is both vague (lacks any details about development environment e.g. platform, OS, compiler), and strange (by being so obvious) requirements. In other words, taken as a whole the question makes the OP appears lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'll definitely want to take a look at libjpeg:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg

Working with bmp files is actually pretty easy, since there isn't any compression to deal with:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: And working with netpbm (http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) is even easier than bmp.